# Four dice puzzle: 2,2,4,5

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers, dice

Damiano has thrown four dice and the numbers **2, 2, 4, 5** showed up on top.
Damiano asks himself:

> **What is the smallest positive integer that cannot be generated with these four numbers according to the following rules?**

- One may use the four numbers 2, 2, 4, 5, and it is fine if not all of them are used.
- Concatenation of digits is NOT allowed.
- The only allowed operations are additions, subtraction, multiplication, and division ($+,-,*,/$).
- One may use any number of brackets.

Examples: $~~~~1=5-4$; $~~~~2=4-2$; $~~~~3=4-(2/2)$; $~~~~4=(4+2)-2$; $~~~~$etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The answer is:**

> **23.**

Joel Rondeau’s answer gives ways of getting anything up to this, except for 17; but 17 = ((4+2)*2)+5.

If I am not mistaken, the full range of positive integer values achievable is

> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,24,25,26,28,30,32,36,38,40,42,44,48,50,56,60,80]

(found using a small Haskell script).

> 1 = ((2-4)*2)+5
> 2 = ((2/2)-4)+5
> 3 = ((4-5)+2)+2
> 4 = ((5-4)*2)+2
> 5 = ((2-4)+2)+5
> 6 = ((2/4)*2)+5
> 7 = ((4+2)*2)-5
> 8 = ((5*2)-4)+2
> 9 = ((2-2)+4)+5
> 10 = ((2/2)+4)+5
> 11 = ((4*2)-2)+5
> 12 = ((4-2)*5)+2
> 13 = ((2+2)+4)+5
> 14 = ((5-2)*4)+2
> 15 = ((4*2)+2)+5
> 16 = ((5*2)+4)+2
> 17 = ((4+2)*2)+5
> 18 = ((5+2)*2)+4
> 19 = (5*4)-(2/2)
> 20 = ((5+4)*2)+2
> 21 = ((2+2)*4)+5
> 22 = ((5+4)+2)*2
> 24 = ((5*4)+2)+2
> 25 = ((2/2)+4)*5
> 26 = ((4*2)+5)*2
> 28 = ((5*2)+4)*2
> 30 = ((5+2)*4)+2
> 32 = ((4+2)*5)+2
> 36 = ((5+2)+2)*4
> 38 = ((5*4)*2)-2
> 40 = ((2+2)+4)*5
> 42 = ((5*4)*2)+2
> 44 = ((5*4)+2)*2
> 48 = ((5*2)+2)*4
> 50 = ((4*2)+2)*5
> 56 = ((5+2)*4)*2
> 60 = ((4+2)*2)*5
> 80 = ((2+2)*4)*5

Comment: A lot of these can be made more readable. For example: *((5-2)X4)+2* could simply be **(4-2)X(5+2)**

Comment: @warspyking: yes, the script just gives the first way it found for each output, not in any way the simplest.  And the first sums it tried were the ones bracketed like ((x @ y) @ z) @ w), so most come out this way.  Actually, I hadn’t noticed at first, but almost every number that can be reached was reached by that bracketing — the only exception was 19.

Comment: Write the script so that it tries without bracketing first?

Comment: @warspyking: right — if I was doing it again, I’d change the order it tried things in.  But I didn’t save the script, and I can’t quite be bothered to write it again now just to get slightly simpler-looking expressions.

Comment: Tell me how you did it specifically, I might write it up in Lua

Comment: @warspyking: I defined five functions for the five possible bracketings, like `t1 o1 o2 o3 x1 x2 x3 x4 = o1 (o2 (o3 x1 x2) x3) x4`.  Then I ran through each of these, each of the 4^3 choices of operators o1, o2, o3, and the 4! permutations of 2,2,4,5 for x1, x2, x3, x4, storing the results along with a record of the inputs, so a big list of tuples like “(17 , 1 , ('+','*','+'), [4,2,2,5])", where the 17 is the output and the 1 means that it used the 1st bracketing.  Then I sorted by output, discarded duplicates, and pretty-printed.  Pretty crude — for scaling up, one could easily improve it.

Comment: I tried to write a Lua script, I ran into a problem with multiple operators, hence: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/23110/2383

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is what you we going for or not, but assuming we can only use *each operator once* (there's no rule specified for this)

**The answer is:**

> **17**

List:

> 2*(5-4)/2 = 1
>  (2-5+4)*2 = 2
>  (2*5-4)/2 = 3
>  2+(5-4)*2 = 4
>  2+5-4/2 = 5
>  (2+5-4)*2 = 6
>  (2*5+4)/2 = 7
>  2*5-4+2 = 8
>  2*(5+4)/2 = 9
>  (2+5)*2-4 = 10
>  (2+5*4)/2 = 11
>  2+5*4/2 = 12
>  2*(5/2+4) = 13
>  (2+5)*4/2 = 14
>  (2+4)*5/2 = 15
>
>  2*(5+4)-2 = 16
>  (2+5/2)*4 = 18
>  4*5-2/2 = 19
>  2+5*4-2 = 20
>  2/2+5*4 = 21
>  (2/2+5)*4 = 24
>  (2/2+4)*5 = 25
>  (2+5)*4-2 = 26
>  (2+4)*5-2 = 28

Also relevant: Your rule about not using each one is irrelevant, any number you can make with less can be made with all of them, at least, up to the smallest number

And if anybody's interested, here's the Lua script used to achieve such results:

> local Numbers = {
>     {2,5,4,2},
>     {2,5,2,4},
>     {2,2,5,4},
>     {2,2,4,5},
>     {2,4,5,2},
>     {2,4,2,5},
>     {4,2,5,2},
>     {4,2,2,5},
>     {4,5,2,2},
>     {5,2,4,2},
>     {5,2,2,4},
>     {5,4,2,2}
>  }
>
>  local Operators = {
>     {'+','/','*','-'},
>
>     {'+','/','-','*'},
>     {'+','-','/','*'},
>
>     {'+','-','*','/'},
>     {'+','*','/','-'},
>
>     {'+','*','-','/'},
>     {'-','+','*','/'},
>
>     {'-','+','/','*'},
>     {'-','/','+','*'},
>
>     {'-','/','*','+'},
>     {'-','*','+','/'},
>
>     {'-','*','/','+'},
>     {'*','+','/','-'},
>
>     {'*','+','-','/'},
>     {'*','-','+','/'},
>
>     {'*','-','/','+'},
>     {'*','/','+','-'},
>
>     {'*','/','-','+'},
>     {'/','+','*','-'},
>
>     {'/','+','-','*'},
>     {'/','-','+','*'},
>
>     {'/','-','*','+'},
>     {'/','*','+','-'},
>
>     {'/','*','-','+'}
>  }
>
>  function BracketForm(eq, f)
>     if f == 0 then
>        return eq
>     elseif f == 1 then
>        return "("..eq:sub(1,3)..")"..eq:sub(4)
>     elseif f == 2 then
>        return eq:sub(1,4).."("..eq:sub(5)..")"
>     elseif f == 3 then
>        return eq:sub(1,2).."("..eq:sub(3,5)..")"..eq:sub(6)
>     elseif f == 4 then
>        return "("..eq:sub(1,5)..")"..eq:sub(6)
>     elseif f == 5 then
>        return eq:sub(1,2).."("..eq:sub(3)..")"
>     elseif f == 6 then
>        return "(("..eq:sub(1,3)..")"..eq:sub(4,5)..")"..eq:sub(6)
>     elseif f == 7 then
>        return eq:sub(1,2).."(("..eq:sub(3,5)..")"..eq:sub(6)..")"
>     end
>  end
>
>  local Found = {}
>
>  for i,v in pairs(Numbers) do
>     for ii,vv in pairs(Operators) do
>        local equation = v[1] .. vv[1] .. v[2] .. vv[2] .. v[3] .. vv[3] .. v[4]
>        for i = 0, 7 do
>           equation2 = BracketForm(equation, i)
>           local ans = load("return " .. equation2)()
>           Found[ans] = ans > 0 and ans%1 == 0 and not Found[ans] and equation2 or nil
>        end
>     end
>  end
>
>  local answers = {}
>  for i, v in pairs(Found) do
>     answers[#answers+1] = i
>  end
>
>  for i = 1,#answers do
>     local least = math.min(table.unpack(answers))
>     local eq = Found[least]
>     for ii = 1, #answers do
>        if answers[ii] == least then
>           table.remove(answers, ii)
>        end
>     end
>     print(eq .."="..least)
>  end