# Four dice puzzle: What's the best throw?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers, dice

This continues Damiano's puzzle "[Four dice puzzle: 2,2,4,5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23072/)"

---

Damiano keeps throwing his four dice. After a lot of throwing and thinking and working, he has determined for every throw $a,b,c,d$ of his four dice the smallest positive integer $N(a,b,c,d)$ that cannot be generated from this throw according to the following rules:

- One may use the four numbers $a,b,c,d$ in any order, and it is fine if not all of them are used.
- Concatenation of digits is NOT allowed.
- The only allowed operations are additions, subtraction, multiplication, and division ($+,-,*,/$).
- One may use any number of brackets.

> **Question:** Which throw $a,b,c,d$ of dice yields the largest number $N(a,b,c,d)$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have an answer of

> 2, 4, 5, 6

Which yields an N of

> 45

Barring a bug in my test program, this should be correct. I tried all possible values.

Here are all the values for my answer:

> 1 = 5 - 4
>  2 = 2
>  3 = 5 - 2
>  4 = 4
>  5 = 5
>  6 = 6
>  7 = 5 + 2
>  8 = 6 + 2
>  9 = 5 + 4
>  10 = 6 + 4
>  11 = 6 + 5
>  12 = 6 * 2
>  13 = 6 + 5 + 2
>  14 = (5 * 4) - 6
>  15 = 6 + 5 + 4
>  16 = (6 * 2) + 4
>  17 = (6 * 2) + 5
>  18 = (5 + 4) * 2
>  19 = (6 * 4) - 5
>  20 = 5 * 4
>  21 = ((6 * 4) + 2) - 5
>  22 = (5 * 4) + 2
>  23 = (5 * 4) + (6 / 2)
>  24 = 6 * 4
>  25 = ((6 + 4) * 2) + 5
>  26 = (6 * 4) + 2
>  27 = ((6 * 4) + 5) - 2
>  28 = (5 + 2) * 4
>  29 = (6 * 4) + 5
>  30 = 6 * 5
>  31 = (6 * 4) + 5 + 2
>  32 = (6 * 5) + 2
>  33 = ((2 / 4) + 5) * 6
>  34 = (6 * 5) + 4
>  35 = ((6 / 2) + 4) * 5
>  36 = (4 + 2) * 6
>  37 = ((6 + 2) * 4) + 5
>  38 = ((5 + 2) * 6) - 4
>  39 = ((5 / 2) + 4) * 6
>  40 = (6 + 2) * 5
>  41 = ((4 + 2) * 6) + 5
>  42 = (5 + 2) * 6
>  43 = (6 * 4 * 2) - 5
>  44 = (6 + 5) * 4
>  45 = ???

Comment: `45 = (6*6)+5+4` or `45 = (6+3) * 5` or am I missing something?

Comment: @VenomFangs You are missing something. Neither of your 2 options can be done with the 4 numbers I used to get 1-44. For example, `6,6,5,4` can get you 45, but it won't get you 33, so it isn't the best option.

Comment: Gotcha, the question was more in depth than I was giving it credit for. Thanks!