# How many consecutive integers can you make using only four digits?

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, open-ended

In the spirit of the classic *four fours*, I wonder what's the optimal set of four numbers?

> Your goal is to make the most consecutive integers using four digits
>   of your choice. Pick four: $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ 
>   ( You can pick multiple instances of the same digit )
>
> When constructing an integer:
>
> - all of your four candidates must be used exactly once (order/placing of digits is irrelevant)
> - You may use basic arithmetic operations $+,-,\times,\div$ and parentheses $()$
> - You may use $a^b$ and $\sqrt[a]{b}$ but at the expense of 2 numbers as you can see
> - You may **not** form new numbers, i.e. $ab$ is not allowed

If we were to use four $4$s, the best we could do would be up to $9$:

```
 0  =  4 ÷ 4 × 4 − 4
 1  =  4 ÷ 4 + 4 − 4
 2  =  4 −(4 + 4)÷ 4  
 3  = (4 × 4 − 4)÷ 4
 4  =  4 + 4 ×(4 − 4)
 5  = (4 × 4 + 4)÷ 4
 6  = (4 + 4)÷ 4 + 4
 7  =  4 + 4 − 4 ÷ 4
 8  =  4 ÷ 4 × 4 + 4
 9  =  4 ÷ 4 + 4 + 4
*10  =  4 ÷√4 + 4 ×√4 
*10  =  (44 − 4) ÷ 4
```

Number 10 **can't be done** and is an example of *failing*, since it would require either:

- *expenseless roots*; $\sqrt{4}$ isn't allowed. ( $\sqrt[2]{4}$ is, which requires you to use $4$ and $2$ )
- *number formation* which isn't allowed either.

Zero does not necessarily need to be included, you can start at  either $0$ or $1$.

---

For the purposes of *freedom of puzzling*, if you think you can top your solution for a chosen set of digits, by starting at **any other positive integer**, you can add that to your answer below your initial solution. *(I suspect this is unlikely)*

If you want, you can extend your consecutive list to negative integers but this is strictly optional and not necessary in any way, other than for the purposes of fulfillment and *mathematical euphoria*.

---

**Example**

There is an example on Puzzling.SE using digits $2,2,4,5$:

> https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/23078/32666

But this can be expanded since the given example uses only basic arithmetic operations, not including potentiation and roots.  I also suspect It could be done better using another set.

I tried this by hand and I'm stuck at number $29$ using this example set, and at number $34$ using $9,8,3,2$.

Comment: Are we allowed to change the order of the digits, e.g. `2 ÷ 3 × 4 − 7` vs. `(7 + 2)÷ 3 + 4`? And are we allowed to put two digits together to make a two-digit number? (`44` is in your example but not allowed by the rules as written - I would vote not to allow it.) Does the list really have to start at 0 or 1 only, or could it start at any other number? (That would make it a slightly more interesting challenge IMHO.)

Comment: Also, what does "at the expense of 2 numbers as you can see" mean?

Comment: @Nathaniel The order of the digits is irrelevant. No, number formation is not allowed, number 10 is shown as an **failed example**, since I wrote before that "best we can do is 9". It can start at 0 or 1 since I was thinking of positive integers, but starting at any number would be more interesting indeed, I'll edit these details a bit. The expense of 2 numbers means if your set contains 2 and 3, to square a 3, you need to use 3^2 and you used up those two numbers.

Comment: in your example, you formed 44 but you say "You may not form new numbers, i.e. abab is not allowed".

Comment: @Oray That is a **failed example**, not valid. Next line reads: " Number 10 can't be done. " Why did $2$ people so far misread that? :|

Comment: @Vepir can I add minus to the beginning? such as $-1+1+1+1$?

Comment: @Oray I don't see why it would be against the rules, so why not.

Comment: Does allowing "$-$" minus at the beginning also mean that any number may be negated? As in $1+1+(-1)+(-1) = 0$ . Either way, it probably should be mentioned in the puzzle statement rather than in comments. Also, either way, it effectively makes more than 4 numbers available for use.

Comment: What you call "number formation" is, I believe, called "concatenation" in math.

Comment: @humn I believe we can avoid "negation"? In your example, you don't need a plus in front of a minus, and that's subtraction then. Also, instead of negating the first number, just move it to the right.  Negation of exponents is also unnecessary since it results in exponentiation+division. Can you give me an example where negation can't be avoided if my intuition is wrong? (Other than if we want to form more negative numbers)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I believe that's just another word for number formation in math. But if you were to use it as a math function, you could do things like $(4+4)||4=84$. I prefer to simply say "number formation" to avoid additional clarifications.

Comment: Good points about rearranging negation, @Vepir. The only contrary examples I can think are quite unlikely to be helpful, such as $3^{-2}+\frac89 = 1$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is my result for $1,4,6,7$ from $1$ to $53$.

> $1^{4-6-7}=1$
>
> $1^4-6+7=2$
>
> $(1-4)/(6-7)=3$
>
> $1+4+6-7=4$
>
> $1-4/(6-7)=5$
>
> $1+4-6+7=6$
>
> $(1^{4})^{6}*7=7$
>
> $1^{4-6}+7=8$
>
> $-1*(4-6-7)=9$
>
> $1-4+6+7=10$
>
> $1^6*(4+7)=11$
>
> $1^6+4+7=12$
>
> $1^4*(6+7)=13$
>
> $1^4+6+7=14$
>
> $(1-6)*(4-7)=15$
>
> $-1+4+6+7=16$
>
> $1*(4+6)+7=17$
>
> $1+4+6+7=18$
>
> $1-6*(4-7)=19$
>
> $-4*(1^7-6)=20$
>
> $-1+4*7-6=21$
>
> $1*(4*7-6)=22$
>
> $1+4*7-6=23$
>
> $1^7*4*6=24$
>
> $1^7+4*6=25$
>
> $4*(1+7)-6=26$
>
> $-4*(1-6)+7=27$
>
> $1^6*4*7=28$
>
> $1^6+4*7=29$
>
> $-1+4*6+7=30$
>
> $1*(4*6+7)=31$
>
> $1+4*6+7=32$
>
> $-1+4*7+6=33$
>
> $1*(4*7+6)=34$
>
> $1+4*7+6=35$
>
> $(7-1)^{6-4}=36$
>
> $-1-4+6*7=37$
>
> $-1*(4-6*7)=38$
>
> $1-4+6*7=39$
>
> $4-6*(1-7)=40$
>
> $6+7*(4+1)=41$
>
> $1^4*6*7=42$
>
> $1^4+6*7=43$
>
> $-4+6*(1+7)=44$
>
> $-1+4+6*7=45$
>
> $1*(4+6*7)=46$
>
> $1+4+6*7=47$
>
> $-1+7^{6-4}=48$
>
> $1*7^{6-4}=49$
>
> $1+7^{6-4}=50$
>
> $-1+4*(6+7)=51$
>
> $1*4*(6+7)=52$
>
> $1+4*(6+7)=53$

Comment: Do you think this might be the optimal set?

Comment: @Vepir I believe this is optimal if I do not mess up with my programming. I checked every possibility.

Comment: I'll most likely accept it at the end of the day. What did you used to program it? Would you mind sharing your code on something like pastebin?

Comment: @Vepir it is c#, code is kinda messy since I edited over something else to do it. I will clean and paste it here later. Probably there will be no better answer if I did not miss something serious in my code :)

Comment: I accepted your answer since it seems it's unlikely that we get a better result. I would still like to check out your code? :)

Comment: @Oray people may still be waiting for the code ^^

Comment: @Cœur I cannot find the code, but you can easily write it by yourself :) it took half of hour to write it to be honest.

Comment: By the way, you may add: `7-6-1^4=0`

Comment: Note that $2,3,8,9$ can also reach $53$ and is the only other such digit set. I added that as a new answer.

Answer (score 5):

I revisited the question, and ran a brute force over all possible cases, and found that there are two optimal solutions. I used the following [github code](https://gist.github.com/Radcliffe/fab1cefe6e2a3a23466539a7ecbc6edb) and modified it a bit to fit my task.

Other than the $1,4,6,7$ digit set that holds the optimal record of $53$ that [Oray found](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/51234/32666), we can also accomplish the same record with digit case $2,3,8,9$:

> $$\begin{array}{}
> 1 = (8 - (2 - 3)) \div 9\\
> 2 = 9 - ((2 - 3) + 8)\\
> 3 = 9 \div (8 - (2 + 3))\\
> 4 = ((2 + 3) + 8) - 9\\
> 5 = ((2 \times 3) + 8) - 9\\
> 6 = ((2 + 3) - 8) + 9\\
> 7 = ((2 \times 3) - 8) + 9\\
> 8 = 9 - ((2 - 3) ^ {8})\\
> 9 = ((2 - 3) ^ {8}) \times 9\\
> 10 = ((2 - 3) ^ {8}) + 9\\
> 11 = 9 - ((2 \times 3) - 8)\\
> 12 = 9 - ((2 + 3) - 8)\\
> 13 = (2 \times (3 + 8)) - 9\\
> 14 = ((2 \div 3) \times 9) + 8\\
> 15 = (9 - (8 \div 2)) \times 3\\
> 16 = ((2 - 3) + 8) + 9\\
> 17 = 9 - ((2 - 3) \times 8)\\
> 18 = 9 - ((2 - 3) - 8)\\
> 19 = 9 - (2 \times (3 - 8))\\
> 20 = 8 - (2 \times (3 - 9))\\
> 21 = (8 \div (2 \div 3)) + 9\\
> 22 = ((2 + 3) + 8) + 9\\
> 23 = ((2 \times 3) + 8) + 9\\
> 24 = ((8 - 2) ^ {3}) \div 9\\
> 25 = ((2 ^ {3}) + 8) + 9\\
> 26 = ((3 ^ {2}) + 8) + 9\\
> 27 = (8 - (2 + 3)) \times 9\\
> 28 = ((2 \times 8) + 3) + 9\\
> 29 = 8 - ((2 - 9) \times 3)\\
> 30 = ((2 + 8) \div 3) \times 9\\
> 31 = ((2 + 3) \times 8) - 9\\
> 32 = (9 - (2 + 3)) \times 8\\
> 33 = 8 - (2 - (3 \times 9))\\
> 34 = ((3 - 8) ^ {2}) + 9\\
> 35 = (2 + (3 \times 8)) + 9\\
> 36 = (2 - 8) \times (3 - 9)\\
> 37 = ((2 + 3) \times 9) - 8\\
> 38 = 2 \times ((3 \times 9) - 8)\\
> 39 = ((2 \times 3) \times 8) - 9\\
> 40 = (2 + (9 \div 3)) \times 8\\
> 41 = (2 ^ {8 - 3}) + 9\\
> 42 = (2 + (8 \div 3)) \times 9\\
> 43 = (2 \times 8) + (3 \times 9)\\
> 44 = ((3 - 9) ^ {2}) + 8\\
> 45 = (9 - (2 - 8)) \times 3\\
> 46 = ((2 \times 3) \times 9) - 8\\
> 47 = 2 - ((3 - 8) \times 9)\\
> 48 = ((2 \div 3) \times 8) \times 9\\
> 49 = ((2 + 3) \times 8) + 9\\
> 50 = 2 - ((3 - 9) \times 8)\\
> 51 = ((8 - 2) \times 9) - 3\\
> 52 = ((8 ^ {2}) - 3) - 9\\
> 53 = ((2 + 3) \times 9) + 8\\
> \end{array}$$

Comment: Similarly to Oray, you also miss 0, (9+2) - (3+8), leading to a total of 54

Comment: @Fifth_H0r5eman The goal is to reach maximal value, so it is still $53$. The $0$ is optional as stated in the question. Edit: I also haven't considered variations such as where starting number is $\ge 1$, which are suggested in the original question (Where in that case we are counting the maximal streak).

Comment: It reads in the question as: "Your goal is to make the most consecutive integers", not reach the maximum end value. 0 would bump this up to 54

Comment: @Fifth_H0r5eman You're right, I should've been more specific when I was writing the question. - As it seems, my idea of "streaks of X integers" boiled down to "up to number X in non-negative or positive integers". Excuse me for not writing the question more clearly.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a list of all numbers from 1 to 43 using 2, 3, 6 and 7. **^** is the power operator.

> `(6-((3+7)/2))`
>  `(6*(3/(2+7)))`
>  `(2/((7-3)/6))`
>  `((6*3)-(2*7))`
>  `((7-(3-6))/2)`
>  `(((7-6)*2)*3)`
>  `(7*((3*2)/6))`
>  `(2^(3*(7-6)))`
>  `((3^(7-6))^2)`
>  `((3^2)+(7-6))`
>  `(((7+3)/2)+6)`
>  `(((7+6)+2)-3)`
>  `(((6/2)+7)+3)`
>  `(7+(6-(2-3)))`
>  `(((6*2)-7)*3)`
>  `(7-(3-(6*2)))`
>  `((6-3)+(7*2))`
>  `((3+(2+6))+7)`
>  `(((3*2)+6)+7)`
>  `(2*((7-3)+6))`
>  `(6-((2-7)*3))`
>  `(7+((2*6)+3))`
>  `((6+3)+(2*7))`
>  `((6/(2/7))+3)`
>  `((7*3)+(6-2))`
>  `(6+((3+7)*2))`
>  `((2+7)*(6-3))`
>  `((2/(3/7))*6)`
>  `(6+((3*7)+2))`
>  `(2*((7*3)-6))`
>  `(7+((6+2)*3))`
>  `(3-(7-(6^2)))`
>  `(3*((7-2)+6))`
>  `(((6/2)^3)+7)`
>  `(((6-3)+2)*7)`
>  `(6*(2-(3-7)))`
>  `((6*(3+2))+7)`
>  `((7-(2/3))*6)`
>  `((3+(7/2))*6)`
>  `((6^2)-(3-7))`
>  `((7*6)-(3-2))`
>  `(((3-2)*6)*7)`
>  `(3-(2-(6*7)))`

As you can guess, I wrote a program to find this. It's not so hard to make one, but I'm disclosing it anyway. It puts the output into spoiler code blocks automatically ;)

The program below doesn't use the root operator because most of the time it's useless. If you want to include it, add 'r' to the `operators` array, but beware of overflow errors.

I stole the RPN parser from [here](http://danishmujeeb.com/blog/2014/12/parsing-reverse-polish-notation-in-python/).

```
import random

operators = ['-', '+', '*', '/', '^']

def parse(rpn):

    stack = []

    for val in rpn:
        if val in operators:
            if len(stack) < 2:
                return -1
            op1 = stack.pop()
            op2 = stack.pop()
            if val=='-': result = op2 - op1
            if val=='+': result = op2 + op1
            if val=='*': result = op2 * op1
            if val=='/':
                if op1 != 0:
                    result = op2 / op1
                else:
                    return -1
            if val=='^':
                if op2 > 0 and op1 < 6:
                    result = op2 ** op1
                else:
                    return -1
            if val=='r':
                if op2 > 0 and op1 != 0:
                    result = op2 ** (1/op1)
                else:
                    return -1

            stack.append(result)
        else:
            stack.append(float(val))

    if len(stack)!= 1:
        return -1
    return stack.pop()


def randrpn(digits):
    rpn = digits[:]
    rpn.append(random.choice(operators))
    rpn.append(random.choice(operators))
    rpn.append(random.choice(operators))
    random.shuffle(rpn)
    return rpn


def randdigits():
    d = []
    d.append(random.choice(range(10)))
    d.append(random.choice(range(10)))
    d.append(random.choice(range(10)))
    d.append(random.choice(range(10)))
    return d

def rpn_to_infix(rpn):
    stack = []
    infix = ""
    for nxt in rpn:
        if nxt in operators:
            op1 = stack.pop()
            op2 = stack.pop()
            expr = '(' + op2 + nxt + op1 + ')'
            stack.append(expr)
        else:
            stack.append(str(nxt))
    return '>! `' + stack.pop() + '`<br>'

d = randdigits()
results = []
formulas = []
for i in range(300000):
    r = randrpn(d)
    res = parse(r)
    if (res >= 0 and res.is_integer() and not res in results):
        results.append(res)
        formulas.append(rpn_to_infix(r))

for i in range(1, 1000):
    if float(i) in results:
        print formulas[results.index(float(i))]
    else:
        break
```

Comment: I suppose you could write a script to translate it into standard notation for readability. I would appreciate it, since I'm doing my own set of digits by hand atm.

Comment: @Vepir Infix converter done.

Comment: Why picking randomly in `randdigits` when there are only 10^4 = 10000 possibilities to brute force it?